# Designing Rayleigh Fading Wireless Channel with particular properties

Tags: matlab, fading-channel

I have some information on particular wireless channel between an Access Point(AP) and K users as described in the picture below:
[image]

How i can create this channel in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
theta0 = 6.25*10^-4;
di = 10; %whatever it is
h = theta0.*.*di^(-3).*(1/sqrt(2)).*(randn(1,500) + 1i.*randn(1,500));
g = theta0.*.*di^(-3).*(1/sqrt(2)).*(randn(1,500) + 1i.*randn(1,500));
```

Comment: The paper said that they averaging over
500 randomized channel realizations.  what is that supposed to mean? Is it equivalent to produce 500 sample? what is the averaging role?

Comment: They compute something using these channels, using one realization a time, and then average over all 500 realizations. For example, suppose they want to compute average BER. Then you need a loop of 500 and find the BER for each realization, sum them up, and then divide the total sum by 500. The average role here is take into account the variations of the channels. In fading channels, the instantaneous performance fluctuates considerably with the channels. The average gives better insights.

Comment: If I answered your question you can choose it as the answer.